# can not instantiate a view controller, swift, ios

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift

I am trying to instantiate a view controller from the nib file like following :

```
class TNAChallengerHandler:ChallengeHandler {

    var controller : ViewController

    // Default initializer
    init(realm iRealm: String, controller iController : ViewController) {
        println("Default initializers")
        self.controller = iController;
        super.init(realm: iRealm)
    }

    // Convience initializer
    convenience init() {
        println("Convience initializers")
        let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)

        self.init(realm: "SingleStepAuthRealm", controller:vc)
    }
```

Executing the codes and I am getting

```
iOS_SingleBasedAdapterAuthentication[40828:5708548] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/tonytran/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6B797313-635F-4ABD-B3C6-A1D9DF3F1E85/
data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FDC3FD2B-6E26-4654-AC0F-ED3F44DDC5F6/iOS_SingleBasedAdapterAuthentication.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''
```

I double check in the storyboard, the custom class of the class is already changed to `ViewController` like below and the name is as same as  `ViewController.swift`

[image]

Any thoughts about this. All comments are welcomed here.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. ViewController will be automatically instantiated when your storyboard is since it's the root view controller of the navigation controller. You shouldn't be using initWithNibName:bundle with a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a nib file named `ViewController`.

You have a storyboard.  A storyboard is compiled into a set of nib files, but you don't access those nib files directly.  Instead, you need to give your view controller a Storyboard ID.  Then you can ask the storyboard to instantiate that view controller.

Let's say you use “GetData” as the Storyboard ID:

[image: storyboard ID]

and I assume your storyboard is named `Main.storyboard`.  Then you can instantiate the view controller like this:

```
convenience init() {
    println("Convenience initializers")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GetData")
    self.init(realm: "SingleStepAuthRealm", controller: vc)
}
```

That said, I'm not sure it makes a lot of sense to instantiate a view controller by name when that view controller is also used as the root view controller of a `UINavigationController`.  Are you sure you want to instantiate a new view controller here?